# Problema com o getMap() da api do google maps - android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Estou estudando a api do google maps e estava usando como base para meu estudos vídeo-aulas disponibilizadas no youtube. No entanto, enquanto estava estudando me deparei com um problema de depreciação de código. A vídeo-aula que estava seguindo está utilizando uma função que já não existe na atual versão do android.
Gostaria que vocês me ajudassem a adaptar o código que possuo para que ele funcione corretamente. A função em questão é a "getMap()" da API que tentei substituir para getMapAsync() (que segundo a documentação, é a função equivalente), mas que também continuou com erro.
O código original em questão é este:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{

private GoogleMap map;
private SupportMapFragment mapFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    GoogleMapOptions options = new GoogleMapOptions();
    options.zOrderOnTop(true);

    mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance(options);
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.llContainer, mapFragment);
    ft.commit();
}

public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

    new Thread(){
        public void run(){

            while(mapFragment.getMap() == null){
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    configMap();
                }
            });

        }
    }.start();
}

public void configMap(){

    map = mapFragment.getMap();
    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);


    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(-23, -46);
    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(latLng).zoom(18).build();
    CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition);

    map.animateCamera(update, 3000, new GoogleMap.CancelableCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            Log.i("Script", "CancelableCallback.OnFinish");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.i("Script", "CancelableCallback.OnCancel");
        }
    });


}
```

Alguém pode me ajudar com este problema, qual mudanças eu preciso fazer para o código funcionar sem erro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Android evolui muito rápido e muito código fica pelo caminho. Este é o problema de seguir tutoriais muito antigos.

Pode até ser que o resto do artigo/vídeo ainda seja relevante, mas o código ficou pra trás e acredito que não pode ser adaptado, por que as diferenças entre  **getMap()** e **getMapAsync()** estão justamente refletidas neste código.

A versão mais nova, obtém o mapa de forma **assíncrona**, que é o que este trecho de código faz:

```
new Thread(){
    public void run(){

        while(mapFragment.getMap() == null){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                configMap();
            }
        });

    }
}.start();
```

Veja esta [página da documentação, em português](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/?hl=pt-br) com código atualizado para obter um googlemap.

public class MapPane extends Activity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map_activity);

    MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.867, 151.206);

    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 13));

    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .title("Sydney")
            .snippet("The most populous city in Australia.")
            .position(sydney));
 }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado por responder!